# Pass PHP array to Jquery Slideshow

Tags: php, jquery

How can I take my array from PHP and populate imagearray in the gallery function?

```
       $leftimages = $images->GetSlideShowImages($userid,$campaignid,$screenid,'midleft');
       var phparray = <?php echo json_encode($leftimages) ?>;
$.each(phparray, function (i, elem) {
           imagesarray.push(elem['image']); 
});



      var mygallery=new gallery({
wrapperid: "temp1_leftshow_f", //ID of main gallery container,
dimensions: [500, 300], 

    imagearray: [
    ["http://myimageurl1.jpg", "", "_new", "text1"],
    ["http://myimageurl2.jpg", "", "_new", "text2"],
    ["http://myimageurl3.jpg", "", "_new", "text3"],
],
```

Comment: You can use PHP to generate the unordered list that you need for the slideshow rather than processing the JSON output with JavaScript.

Comment: You've posted an ugly mix of JavaScript and PHP, and haven't even bothered to make sure your brackets balance. Please put a little more effort into your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point where you see the javascript array being formed you could inject some PHP to output the values.

For example:

```
imagearray: [
<?php
    // LOOP AND PRINT
    // e.g. print('["http://myimageurl1.jpg", "", "_new", "text1"],');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $leftimages = $images->GetSlideShowImages($userid,$campaignid,$screenid,'midleft');
   var phparray = <?php echo json_encode($leftimages) ?>;
 $.each(phparray, function (i, elem) {
       imagesarray.push(elem['image']); 
     });



  var mygallery=new gallery({
   wrapperid: "temp1_leftshow_f", //ID of main gallery container,
   dimensions: [500, 300], 

imagearray: [
<? for ($i=1;$i++,$i<4){?>
<?php echo $comma; $comma=",";?>["http://myimageurl<?php echo $i;?>.jpg", "", "_new", "text<?php echo $i;?>"]
 <?php }?>
 ],
```